# for loop: Can't store dataframes in list

Tags: r, list, web-scraping

I created a function using `for` loops (*I know it's not the best way to create loops in R but don't know any other way for this task*). The objetive of the function is to take a group of google search URLs, scrape them for SERPs (*Search Engine Result Pages*) and run topic analysis in them.

The function works, my problem is in this line of code:

`out_list[(4*(url - 1)) + (topics - 1)] <- df_LDA`

It doesn't store the complete `df_LDA` data frame into the `out_list` but only the first column (`topic`).

`df_LDA` has 4 columns: `topic`, `term`, `beta` and `term2`.

I get this error message:

```
There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In out_list[(4 * (url - 1)) + (topics - 1)] <- df_LDA :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

This is my code in order to make the example reproducible.

```
library(tidyverse); library(rvest); library(googlesheets4); library(tidytext)
library(topicmodels)

# Read Google Sheet with queries
gs4_deauth()
queries <- read_sheet("1LarbbUErfnJIe00XKvXXkkfuTFOSNzDNUeuXTkxeIe0", 
                      sheet = 1, range = "A2:B")

scrap_google <- function(df){
  out_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df)*4)
  for(url in 1:nrow(df)){
    df_scrap <- read_html(as.character(df[url,2])) %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = "//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/text()") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      .[. != ">"] %>% 
      .[!. %in% c("Todos los resultados", "De cualquier fecha", 
                  "Buscar páginas en Español", " · ", " ")] %>% 
      .[!str_detect(., pattern = "[\n]")] %>% 
      .[nzchar(.)] %>% 
      tibble(id = seq(1:length(.)), title  = ., text = .) %>% 
      unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
      anti_join(tibble(word = tm::stopwords("spanish"))) %>% 
      count(word, id) %>%
      cast_dtm(id, word, n) %>% 
      as.matrix()
    for(topics in 2:5){
      df_LDA <- LDA(x = df_scrap, k = topics, method = "Gibbs", 
          control = list(seed = 1)) %>% 
        tidy(matrix = "beta") %>% 
        group_by(topic) %>% 
        top_n(7, beta) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        mutate(term2 = fct_reorder(term, beta)) 
      names(out_list)[(4*(url - 1)) + (topics - 1)] <- 
        paste(as.character(df[url, 1]), topics, sep = "_")
      out_list[(4*(url - 1)) + (topics - 1)] <- df_LDA
      print(ggplot(df_LDA, aes(term2, beta, fill = as.factor(topic))) + 
              geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + 
              facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = 'free') +
              coord_flip() + ggtitle(df[url, 1]))  
    }
  }
}

# Run analysis  
beta_list <- scrap_google(df = queries)
```

Comment: You need to specify both row and columns in df[rows, columns] format.  So add a comma for all columns: `out_list[(4*(url - 1)) + (topics - 1), ] <- df_LDA`

Comment: @SteveM ```out_list``` is a list not a dataframe

Comment: try double square brackets `out_list[[(4*(url - 1)) + (topics - 1)]] <- df_LDA`

Comment: @the-mad-statter thank you sir, that did the trick